# how to upload the image to folder using nodejs and save the path into mongodb?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, mongodb, express

i want to upload image using angularjs or html5,Express.jsjs and mongodb.i have followed tutorials i can't able to upload the image to upload folder please some one help me how to do that.below i have given my schema code

```
my schema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    UserName: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
    },
    Avatar: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true

    },
    Email: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    Password: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }
});
```

i want to upload the image with user details

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="Avatar" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="text" name="UserName" id="name">
    <input type="email" name="Email" id="email">
    <input type="password" name="Password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

one more thing i want to store image to some folder like upload and path should be store in database.help me out .thanks for your response

Comment: Can you try https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper - Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: please can you share your routes and controller

Comment: after uploadiing i am gettiing response like this {"message":"0 file(s) uploaded successfully!","files":[]}

Answer (score 2):

You can use nodejs formidable and fs-extra module for creating folder to store image in your application.**Try this**

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var EmpDetail   = require('../models/employee.model.js');//This line means that I am having my schema code.
var    util = require('util');


app.route('/upload').post(function(req,res){

res.json({success:true});

var empData = new EmpDetail();//Here I created object to call my schema values.

var form   =  new formidable.IncomingForm();
console.log(req.body,'req.body');
form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files){
    console.log('dfgbfbf');
    util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files});
});

form.on('field',function(name,value){//This means your html input fields
    console.log('fields',name,value);
    if(name == 'fullName'){
        console.log('here',value);
        empData.fullName = value;
    }
    if(name == 'fatherName'){
        empData.fatherName = value;
    }
    if(name == 'dt'){
        empData.DOB = value;
    }
});
form.on('file',function(field, file){//This means on click of file it gets that file.
    console.log(file.name,'hjgjg');
    var temp = file.path;
    console.log(temp,'temp',file.name);
    var fileName = file.name;
        var fileName = file.name;
        var location     = 'images/';
        var cpLocation   = 'empDetails/images/';
        empData.imgSize = file.size;
        empData.imgType = file.type;
        empData.picFile = location+fileName;//Here PicFile is name of Avatar in model
fs.copy(temp,cpLocation+fileName ,function(err){//This means it create a folder and name of the image in your app.
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

});
form.on('end',function(fields, files){

        empData.save(function(err,resobj){
            if(err)
            {    
               throw err;
            }
        });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a small node module called [skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper) which can handle file uploads. Install it with: `npm install skipper --save`. Since you are using express your main file should look something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(require('skipper')());

app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
  req.file('avatar').upload(function (err, uploadedFiles) {

  if (err) return res.send(500, err);
    return res.json({
      message: uploadedFiles.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
      files: uploadedFiles
    });
  });
});
```

And your html form should look something like:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="avatar" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

*Note: This route will return json object.*

Comment: where it can upload folder or database

Comment: Please check out the options in skipper: https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper#options

Comment: after uploading i am getting response like this {"message":"0 file(s) uploaded successfully!","files":[]}

Comment: For some reason the file is not uploaded. Print everything to find out what is the problem and double check names & paths. Also make sure that you have write/read permissions in the upload folder.

Comment: i am able to get everything except the path