# Any simple example of uploading image by NodeJs in FileSystem and saving the path in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, image, mongodb, upload, filesystems

I have been searching the net for a while, but I couldn't find any simple example of uploading multiple images in Filesystem using NodeJs+(maybe Multer) and saving their paths in MongoDB.

I have found this question the same, but it seems the answers are not working for me.
[how to upload the image to folder using nodejs and save the path into mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534207/how-to-upload-the-image-to-folder-using-nodejs-and-save-the-path-into-mongodb?rq=1)

So far I have been able to save the images in FileSystem.
here is what I have proceed so far.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "file_upload",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.14.2",
    "express": "4.13.3",
    "multer": "1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "should": "~7.1.0",
    "mocha": "~2.3.3",
    "supertest": "~1.1.0"
  }
}
```

**Server.js:**

```
var express =   require("express");
var bodyParser =    require("body-parser");
var multer  =   require('multer');
var app =   express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('userPhoto',2);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){
  upload(req,res,function(err) {
    //console.log(req.body);
    //console.log(req.files);
    if(err) {
        return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    }
    res.end("File is uploaded");
  });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
   console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

**Index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>File upload Node.</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="uploadForm"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="/api/photo"
      method="post">
  <input type="file" name="userPhoto" multiple />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  <input type='text' id='random' name='random'><br>
  <span id = "status"></span>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#uploadForm').submit(function() {
    $("#status").empty().text("File is uploading...");
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        error: function(xhr) {
      status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
        },
        success: function(response) {
    console.log(response)
        $("#status").empty().text(response);
        }
  });
  return false;
});     
});
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I really appreciate if you could give me some hint how I can add mongoDB here to save the path accordingly in mongoDB and how to retrieve the images in this case.

update answer: thanks to @flott

**server.js**

```
var express =   require("express");
var bodyParser =    require("body-parser");
var multer  =   require('multer');
var multerdragdrop = require('multer');
var app =   express();
var http=require("http").Server(app);
var socket=require("socket.io")(http);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Path for loading static files
app.use("/FrontEnd/css",express.static(__dirname+'/public/FrontEnd/css'));
app.use("/FrontEnd/js",express.static(__dirname+'/public/FrontEnd/js'));     app.use("/FrontEnd/partials",express.static(__dirname+'/public/FrontEnd/partials    '));
app.use("/uploads",express.static(__dirname+'/uploads'));
app.use("/FrontEnd/Pictures",express.static(__dirname+'/public/FrontEnd/Pictures'));
var connect=require('./AdditionServerSide/MongoDbLib');

//Multer Storeage
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
  callback(null, __dirname+'/uploads');
 },
 filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
 }
     });

var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('userPhoto',8);
var uploaddragdrop=multerdragdrop({ storage : storage }).array('file',8);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});
//Image Upload form
app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        //console.log(req.body);
           console.log( req.files[0].destination);
        //console.log( req.files[0].filename);
        //console.log( req.files[0].path);

 connect.addvalues('mongodb://localhost:27017/testimages','storedimages',req.file     s[0].filename,req.files[0].destination);

         if(err) {
              return res.end("Error uploading file.");
         }
         res.end("File is uploaded");

         });
});
     //Drag and Drop Form Control
      app.post('/photos',function(req,res){
      uploaddragdrop(req,res,function(err){

      if(err){

        return res.end("Error Uploading file");
      }else {
       //console.log(req.files[0].originalname);

        //connect.addvalues('mongodb://localhost:27017/testimages','storedimages',req.files[0].originalname,req.files[0].path);
       return res.end("Success");
      }

   });

 });
//******** Socket Function to receive data *********

socket.on('connection',function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
// console.log("A user has disconnected");
 });

  socket.on('Latitude', function(msg){

   // console.log("Latitude"+ msg);
  });

  socket.on('Longitude', function(msg){
  // console.log("Longittude"+msg);
  });

   //Request from page to load images
    socket.on("LoadImage",function(msg){
  //Connect to data base and extract images
     connect.establishConnection("mongodb://localhost:27017/testimages","storedimages    ",null,null,function(results){
      if(results!=undefined) {
         if(msg.toUpperCase()=="YES"){
           socket.emit("ImageUploads", results+','+__dirname);
      }
     }
    })


  });
});`
```

**MongoDBLib.js**

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

module.exports= {

establishConnection: function (connectionstring, databasename, queryby, queryval, callback) {
var filenames=[];
var filepaths=[];
var results;

mongodb.connect(connectionstring, function (err, db) {
  if (callback) {
    callback();
  }
  if (!err) {
      var cursor=db.collection(databasename).find();
      cursor.each(function(err,doc){
        if(doc!=null) {
          callback(doc.filename+","+doc.filepath);
        }
      })
  }
  else
    console.log("Error happened");
    });
  },
  addvalues: function (connectionstring, databasename, filename, filepath,      callback) {
    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
mongodb.connect(connectionstring, function (err, db) {

  var collec = db.collection(databasename);
  if (collec != null) {
    db.collection('storedimages').insert({
      "filename": filename,
      "filepath": filepath
 }, {w: 1}, function (err, records) {

         if (records != null) {
        console.log("Record added");
        db.close();
        }
      else
        console.log("Cannot add");
    });

     }
      else {
         console.log("Database not found! error");
       }
     });
  },

retrievevalues: function ( connectionstring, databasename, filename, filepath, callback) {
  if (callback) {
    callback();
  }
  mongodb.connect(connectionstring, function (err, db) {

    var collec = db.collection(databasename);
    if (collec != null) {
      db.collection('storedimages').find({"filename":filename,"filepath":filepath},{w:1},function(err,records){
        if(records!=null) {
          console.log("Record retrieved");
          db.close();
        }
        else
          console.log("Cannot retrieve");
      });

    }
    else {
      console.log("Database not found! error");
    }
  });
}
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, install mongoDB (if you haven't already) and make sure that it is running. Then you can connect to the mongoDB server by:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var db;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, Db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('CONNECTED TO MONGODB');
        db = Db;
    }
});
```

then you can insert things to the database in collection 'yourCollection' by:

```
var collection = db.collection('yourCollection');
collection.insertOne(data, (err, r) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('OK');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I have already installed mongoDB, but there are some problems, first localhosts are different, in my code I am using `app.listen(3000,function(){
   console.log("Working on port 3000"); });` while in your you are using `MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, Db)`. how I can change my code to insert your code without any conflicts?

Comment: and another point is that where I should put the path of the image which I have uploaded in the code above and what is the primary key to access to it to retrieve it?

Comment: Your `app.listen` is for your express server while `MongoClient.connect` is for the **mongoDB** server, they are two different things, you can and probably should have both. 

The first code snippet in my answer you can add for example under `app.use(bodyParser.json());`. The second snipped you should use when you want to insert a path to the DB. You should probably read some about how to store stuff in mongoDB.

Comment: thanks I got it. I used **req.files[0].filename** and **req.files[0].path** for the name of the image and its path, but in my problem I have to upload multiple images, I tried **[:]** or other possibilities. None worked. I looked at **multer** repository. Unfortunately, there is not much explanation there.

Comment: I don't really know anything about multer but if you manage to get all of your desired entries you can use collection.insertMany() to insert them all into the DB.

Comment: thanks alot for your help. now I am saving images in filesystem and the corresponding path in mongoDB.